# Core Data API usage best patterns in iOS 10

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, ios10

I was looking last time for some books related to Core Data in iOS 10, especially covering subjects like Query Generations, NSPersistentContainer, how to setup my Contexts hierarchy in new API with their new concurrency model, and so on.

I read that now every context should have their parents set to `nil`, and the best way is to connect every Context directly to the Persistent Story Coordinator. There is no need to setup parent/child relationships between context if our goal is to responsive UI in our application. I have questions such as:

1. Do I need to use the `container.newBackgroundContext()` method to create context each time I need some task to perform in background or should I create one context and store it somewhere and reuse it for better performance? How many context I can create? What is the best number of background contexts?
2. Do I need to setup the `container.viewContext` parent to some private context created from `container.newBackgroundContext()`?
3. What is the best approach to create a background task that is updating some data in the background thread on not main queue and inform about this main `viewContext`?
4. What is the best way to inform background context that about changes in model that user introduced in main `viewContext` in UI?
5. Do you know some books that covers those topics including architecture and concurrency changes in iOS 10?

Comment: [this course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-9-apps-swift/id1104579961) has two lectures that cover core data. It is the basics, but I think it could be useful as an starting point.

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't generally need to do this. Create a background context for a particular task and then tear it down. Alternatively, `NSPersistentContainer` has a method `performBackgroundTask()`: just pass a block to this and it will create a new private context for you to run this block.
2. Nope. `NSPersistentContainer` deals with that for you.
3. If you observe the `viewContext` for changes, then as long as you do a save in any of your background queues, this change will percolate up. Alternatively, use an `NSFetchResultsController` which has a lot of delegate methods that help you respond to changes.
4. You don't need to do this. Just do what you need to in a private queue and your merge policy will dictate what happens for conflicts.
5. Unfortunately, the changes are still relatively new. Read the documentation for `NSPersistentContainer` and also the [What's New in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017342-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) page.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I need to clarify something. **3** Does the changes from private context will be pushed to the viewContext without setting `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` on viewContext? What about **4**? When I save viewContext does my private context will se this changes without setting on private context `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`?

Comment: No, but why are you interested in a private context being able to merge changes from the parent? This property is more useful when creating a child mainQueue context where you want to see any changes main to the `viewContext`.

Comment: My use case scenario is that I have background task that is searching some data from backend. The search criteria are stored in local db so when task is fired the query is created based on this stored data and request is made. So if user modify this search criteria in UI my background task needs to see this changes and prepare request according to the new criteria that user set. This background task from the other hand is importing some data that UI should be able to display.

Comment: For #4 : Treat `viewContext` as readonly (as the docs say that you should) and ONLY write using `performBackgroundTask`.  `performBackgroundTask` internally has a queue so only one write happens at a time. If you do this there will be no merge conflicts and no need for a mergePolicy.

Comment: @JonRose Your comment about not saving using the `viewContext` is inaccurate. The `viewContext` property is tagged as "(read-only)" in the docs because it has no setter. This is consistent with the rest of the documentation on other `NSPersistentContainer` "(read-only)" properties such as `name` and `managedObjectModel`.

Comment: You are correct; I misread the documentation.  But you should still write to the database in a single synchronous way or you will get write conflicts.  Either ONLY write to the viewContext and never use any other context, or one write with a single queue and NEVER write the viewContext.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to true on any context, it will merge changes from any parent context. In iOS 10, any contexts created by the `NSPersistentContainer` have the container's `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` as a parent. The effect is that if you set this to true on your `viewContext`, changes saved on any `newBackgroundContext` will automatically merge and vice versa.

Comment: Is there any reason to not use this feature? It is false by default because for backward compatibility or from different reasons?

Comment: Well, if you wanted your contexts to be isolated, you might not want changes to automatically merge. Or if you wanted to control the merge, you would write your own code to catch the save notification and choose to merge or not. In most cases, I would set this to true. It's also new in iOS 10, so they probably default to false so the behavior wouldn't change for everybody.

Comment: @Jerry did you mean: any contexts created by the NSPersistentContainer have persistent store as parent ?

Comment: Actually, I meant to say they have the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` as parent. I'll fix that.